# Subreport wont Display in the Mainreport (Jasperreports)

Tags: report, subreport, subreports

iam very new to Jasperreports and actually i try to display a Subreport through my Mainreport. When i run them alone, both of them working correctly, but when i try to drag and drop a Supreport from the pallet and follow the wizard the Subreport wont display when i run the Mainreport. I try to figure out the problem since one week but nothing works for me.

this is the Mainreport XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-05-15T13:46:24 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2f6e4db4-9f8f-4ffe-9759-6e1fd142f492">
    <property name="template.type" value="columnar"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="src/dataset1.xml"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="bcf9a7c3-f040-47c7-b8b0-ffdf33b6fd91">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="src/dataset1.xml"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="reportName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reportName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="workdirectory" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[workdirectory]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="konectorStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[konectorStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="connectionStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[connectionStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="stuckedCard" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[stuckedCard]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="testSteps" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[testSteps]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="shortDescription" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[shortDescription]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="testResult" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[testResult]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.Class">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[class]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="authentication" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[authentication]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="81" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="70" width="551" height="1" uuid="dee835ad-ce13-4185-a455-2fc7cd2599d3"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" uuid="ca49ecc2-99c4-466b-93f0-1e91dc52bb72"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Konnektorsimmulator Testfall Protokoll: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="400" y="-5" width="153" height="65" uuid="4846b814-11f5-4b15-8c3b-edf1de2288a1"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["/home/r4ff1/Dropbox/Arbeit/image.2UJ5YY.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="553" height="30" uuid="b457f83a-3553-49a9-9cec-fc01637f5192"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="468" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="7" width="453" height="30" uuid="8f7f0d01-07c8-41ae-af38-c6176d26bde1"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="7" width="100" height="30" uuid="8336a307-e230-47e7-b1e7-a7c087dd67b5"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="37" width="453" height="33" uuid="bebc9514-dc72-4da9-84fd-bdb22e82bec0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{shortDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="37" width="100" height="30" uuid="7fec7ae1-18d5-4ae5-87d0-bbc3ac0f5828"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Kurzbeschreibung:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="102" y="70" width="449" height="40" uuid="822b3688-6187-4bb9-95fd-14fb63be4dbe"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="70" width="100" height="30" uuid="4bf8f337-b139-424c-a90e-3340688edace"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Beschreibung:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="121" width="100" height="30" uuid="21780a8f-dd43-47b3-aa45-d1a54f0641ce"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Eingangsdaten: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="120" width="353" height="31" uuid="658e2f24-3dd0-4f3b-8eda-a252ba28b01f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{konectorStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="120" width="100" height="30" uuid="f6406ac6-26cf-40da-8252-41453c65d981"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Konnektor Status: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="150" width="351" height="30" uuid="f70adee8-c72a-40d6-a098-4d0238e05bb2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{connectionStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="150" width="100" height="30" uuid="11dd9b77-4c93-4511-b921-ccce6e909d9e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Verbindungsstatus: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="180" width="351" height="30" uuid="a7797ecd-5f75-4cb2-bb28-0b3f64013e14"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{authentication}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="180" width="100" height="30" uuid="eebc28e8-2029-4022-9cb0-8e77f858528c"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Authentifizierung: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="210" width="351" height="30" uuid="b0918e89-10fb-4874-9d23-002921d43ae0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{workdirectory}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="210" width="100" height="30" uuid="d2ad59b8-5a55-499d-96d7-31b8cc8d2c63"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Dienstverzeichnis]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="240" width="161" height="30" uuid="28604659-6643-4db1-ba85-f59d4a456fd0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stuckedCard}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="102" y="240" width="288" height="30" uuid="158c9fe5-035b-41ea-80ac-7024f427861f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gesteckte Karten(Mandat > Terminal < Karte): ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="2" y="280" width="551" height="1" uuid="49e79677-a0a1-4116-bc6c-b975aff6e535"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="290" width="278" height="20" uuid="06dc0bc1-cd12-443b-a022-787e42319171"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Schritt1: Karte Stecken
]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="310" width="551" height="40" uuid="d7663160-f2c1-4340-ae38-d5a10405a343"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Das Primärsystem führt beim ersten Stecken der Karte im Quartal automatisch eine online-Prüfung und Aktualisierung der eGK durch.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="350" width="288" height="30" uuid="9c4d4fe2-f29f-49c2-ae5a-9ee11aa32f06"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gesteckte Karten(Mandat > Terminal < Karte): ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="290" y="350" width="263" height="30" uuid="374ced41-210a-46c8-90ad-4462f3dd0f40"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stuckedCard}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="380" width="330" height="20" uuid="d3e9af6d-ac4e-4e28-b31d-79a4372017ec"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Prüfungsergebnis zu Schritt: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="401" width="435" height="67" uuid="6c1ff3e6-e67d-40b4-b92f-235b2b5ecb4d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{testResult}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="400" width="100" height="30" uuid="a6c8dbc1-30b9-4b70-be48-993e27dc59c8"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Testergebnise: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="430" width="100" height="30" uuid="0cc928fa-e11a-4842-9fdf-1bdbd245ae9a"/>
                <text><![CDATA[testSteps]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="430" width="467" height="30" uuid="02395e47-6859-4b19-b1a7-75bb4e8fcc7b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{testSteps}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="1" y="467" width="551" height="1" uuid="5cfaaf0b-22ea-4406-aef0-7f1a8551bcde"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="10" y="467" width="551" height="1" uuid="a4306707-5834-428b-a540-f46b52f43c28"/>
            </line>
        </band>
        <band height="468">
            <subreport overflowType="NoStretch">
                <reportElement key="" x="30" y="40" width="450" height="222" uuid="123d247f-df6b-418e-802e-4d09eacccbea"/>
                <subreportParameter name="Name ">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{reportName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="253" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="240" width="555" height="13" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#9DB1B8" uuid="bfdca178-800d-445c-9a31-bb616a00e8ce"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2fba0f87-635e-476d-858f-d102b26146fe"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" mode="Transparent" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e454d23d-bcfc-4c79-a399-0ef520a3150a"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="0" width="197" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="14d8de1e-8695-4078-a67f-0e69172574d5"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport overflowType="NoStretch">
                <reportElement key="" style="Row" stretchType="ElementGroupBottom" x="30" y="40" width="450" height="222" uuid="90cb3729-2abe-4b9a-b5c7-541063f99b74"/>
                <subreportParameter name="Name ">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{reportName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And This is the Supreport XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-05-15T13:48:15 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="13acf49e-4913-4d1b-bccc-113817ad15d1">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="src/dataset1.xml"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="reportName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reportName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="workdirectory" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[workdirectory]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="konectorStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[konectorStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="connectionStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[connectionStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="stuckedCard" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[stuckedCard]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="testSteps" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[testSteps]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="shortDescription" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[shortDescription]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="testResult" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[testResult]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.Class">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[class]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="authentication" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[authentication]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="352">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-20" y="110" width="551" height="1" uuid="b7dd4853-cf98-4e96-8388-f0ba3269ef57"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-20" y="211" width="551" height="1" uuid="dbabfe43-16ab-4c4f-9c86-73519692523a"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="288" height="30" uuid="6906ae91-f112-4073-ae81-9b27dcc2b72b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gesteckte Karten(Mandat > Terminal < Karte): ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="20" uuid="42a1543f-f2ac-4a42-9331-b3eca5690b9c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Schritt1: Karte Stecken
]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="180" height="20" uuid="ff671021-bef7-4cfa-b925-573a21971feb"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Prüfungsergebnis zu Schritt: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="178" width="100" height="30" uuid="84495cdb-5498-4622-ac32-082b8c142740"/>
                <text><![CDATA[testSteps]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="110" width="100" height="30" uuid="67ae3d16-c288-4809-807a-2b5e0a0e474d"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Testergebnise: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="110" width="465" height="68" uuid="8cee8a00-83f5-49da-aff4-afc566f853fa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{testResult}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="182" width="465" height="30" uuid="6d909ecc-2828-40af-a40f-81a3d994db0c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{testSteps}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I hope that somebody can help me with that....
Greetings: Raffaela

Answer (score 1):

you are using an XML-File as datasource for both reports. For the subreport to show data you have to give it the exact datasource through the datasource expression instead of the connection expression. The subreport does not locate the xml file on your filesystem.

Go to the subreport properties and empty the field "Connection Expression". Then fill the Datasource Expression with

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("//")
```

You seem to have an empty query string to your XML file so no xpath query string is needed. This solution should work for **Jasperstudio 6.x.**

---

Another solution could be to pass the $P{XML_DATA_DOCUMENT} parameter to the supreport using the parameters button.